# WP_query shortcode inside acf Repeater breaks the repeater loop

Tags: wp-query, loop, shortcode, advanced-custom-fields

I have a shortcode that lists CPTs and works great everywhere but if I use the shortcode in an ACF repeater the reapeater stops repeating right after the shortcode. I tried reseting postdata in various way in the shortcode, but nothing has worked yet. Appreciate any guidance.

```
<section id="consumer_resources-list" class="padding-top-1">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="accordion margin-bottom-0" data-accordion role="tablist" data-allow-all-closed="true">
            <?php while (have_rows('field_61134ad5cf0b3')): the_row(); ?>
              <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item >
                <a href="#" class="accordion-title h5 margin-0"><?= get_sub_field('field_61134b21cf0b4') ?></a>
                <div class="accordion-content margin-horizontal-1" data-tab-content>
                    <div class="inner-content">
                        <?= get_sub_field('field_61134b4bcf0b5') ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
              </li>
            <?php   endwhile;  ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

This is the shortcode in function.php

```
add_shortcode( 'list_webinars', 'getting_webinars' );

function getting_webinars($atts, $content = null) {
ob_start();

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'language' => 'spanish',
        'webinarcat' => '',
    ), $atts));

    $futureposts = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type'         => 'webinar',
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        //'tax_query' => array(
        'tax_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'webinar_categories',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms' =>$webinarcat,
            ),
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'webinar_categories',
                'field'    => 'slug',
                'terms' =>$language,
            )
        ),
        'meta_key'          => 'webinar_date',
        'meta_value'        => date('Ymd', strtotime('-1 day')),
        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
        'order'             => 'ASC',
        'meta_compare'      => '>',
    ));

    if ($futureposts-> have_posts()){
        
        $retour='<ul class="events-list" style="list-style:none;">';

        while ( $futureposts->have_posts() ) : $futureposts->the_post();
                
$retour .= '<li class="  ' . implode (' ', get_post_class( 'individualWebinar' ) ). '">';
$retour.=    '<span class="event-title-webinar"><a href="' . get_field('field_627d909680aac') . '" target="_blank"> ' . ucfirst($language) . '-';           
$dateTime = strtotime(get_field('field_627d84f3648f2'));
$retour .= date('l, F j, Y', $dateTime) . ' ';
$retour .= '@ '. get_field( "field_627eeb2af6475" ) . ' MST - Register Here >></a></span> </li> ';      
        endwhile; 
        $retour .= '</ul>';         
        return $retour;

    } else { return '<strong>No upcoming events are currently on the calendar.</strong>'; }
wp_reset_postdata();
return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the end to proper syntax,

```
        endwhile; 
        $retour .= '</ul>';         
        wp_reset_postdata();    
        return $retour;
        
    } else { return '<strong>No upcoming events are currently on the calendar.</strong>'; }

return ob_get_clean();  

}
```